# Gnuradio companion not installed after running build-gnuradio script

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I tried installing **Gnuradio 3.7.9.2** using **build-gnuradio** script and apart from a few hiccups due to some packages (which I installed and re-ran the script again) , the script completed its run successfully (I enabled the verbose  option of the script to check the output). I  even added the PYTHONPATH to the .bashrc script after completing the installation. When I tried launching gnuradio-companion though, it doesnt recognise the command.

**:~$ gnuradio-companion
The program 'gnuradio-companion' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gnuradio**

So, I was wondering whether I need to install grc separately after the build-gnuradio script installation ?. I apologise if this is too simple, I  have tried the installation many times and searched the web for problems like this. To the best of my efforts, I was not able to find any. It would be great, if anyone can point to any existing question similar to this, or guide me in fixing this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to use [PyBOMBS](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/pybombs/wiki) to install GNU Radio. Installing Out-of-Tree modules (OOTs) will be much easier afterwards. As for your problem: Did you check if your $PATH variable (`echo $PATH`) contains /usr/local/bin/? This should be the default installation path for a non-system install of GNU Radio.
Alternatively you can try to run `/usr/local/bin/gnuradio-companion`.